# Creating Report With Report Viewer Using Mysql and C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, reportviewer

I have a problem when viewing a report using dataset in c# with mysql database, i create it using programmatically code. i have tried many articles in the internet but my report still not showing. is it possible creating report with report viewer using C# and MySQL?

here is my code

```
private void reporttest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string comm = "select * from t_pejabat";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Program.konek);
        MySqlCommand comd = new MySqlCommand(comm, conn);
        conn.Open();
        DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(comd);
        da.Fill(ds, "isi");
        conn.Close();


        this.reportViewer1.Reset();
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("isi", ds.Tables[0]));
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

here is the error picture
[error](http://i44.tinypic.com/23mdls.png)

Comment: Can you post you code snippet....

Comment: Can you provide more details like type of report? Is it SSRS or Crystal Reports?

Comment: i am using data report that included in vs 2010

Comment: Any error messages ? Without providing more details, nobody can answer your question now ...

Answer (score 1):

Usually this error appear because `reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath` is not setted.

You can do it by code or using form designer.